# Alexa Skill Beta testing worked fine on the day which i accepted the invite then fails to launch skill

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, beta-testing

I provided myself for beta testing the skill but after giving the access and the acceptance for beta testing it worked fine for a day and the next day without changing any code it was not able to recognize the skill, So I logged out and logged in again and it worked fine but when I tested the same with an Alexa device the issue was replicated but logging out and in didn't solve the issue this time.

I need help with this one.

My Alexa skill is hosted in Lambda function in north Virginia server and I am using it from India, I know some will suggest having the same server but then how come it worked fine for the first time then?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, we should change the language setting to English (IN) if the Alexa skill is built-in English(IN) and the region from which it is accessed is India and Vica-Versa.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an explanation and steps to fix this issue. There is a locale discrepancy between your skill, your account, and your Alexa App. In order to use a skill, the skill's language model must match the user's account location as well as the app's location.

This means on one account, you will only be able to see and test skills from one marketplace at a time. So, if you've got your developer account configured for the US, and your skill only has a en-IN language model, you won't be able to see and test it in your Alexa app.

There are two options available to fix this issue, first option is just for developers:

-Option 1- The simplest solution is to create a new language tab for your skill within developer portal that matches the language setting of your app and device. For information on creating a new language model for your skill, please follow this link: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/develop-skills-in-multiple-languages.html#add-a-language-to-an-existing-skill

-Option 2- You can configure your account for a region that matches the language model you currently have set up for your skill. To do this, first make sure the device you're testing on is registered to your developer account, and then that it is set up for the correct language and location in its device settings. For actually configuring your account itself for that marketplace, you'll need to go through the retail Amazon site. Follow these steps:

1. Navigate to https://www.amazon.com/
2. Go to "Your Account" > "Your devices and content" > "Change your digital and device settings" > “Preferences”
3. In "Preferences" click on the "Country/Region Settings" section
4. If the country is not the same as the marketplace you need to test, change it to match